# how to make buttons accessible throughout the page in windows phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have a few buttons which i want to use throughout my application.

My xaml is:

```
 <Button Content="" Grid.Row="1" Height="79" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="9,643,0,0" Name="Home" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="77" BorderThickness="0" Click="Home_Click" />
    <Button Content="" Grid.Row="1" Height="74" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="108,646,0,0" Name="Map1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="67" BorderThickness="0" Click="Map1_Click" />
    <Button Content="" Grid.Row="1" Height="71" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="198,649,0,0" Name="City1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="70" BorderThickness="0" Click="City1_Click" />
    <Button Content="" Grid.Row="1" Height="74" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="295,647,0,0" Name="Cuisine1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="74" BorderThickness="0" Click="Cuisine1_Click" />
    <Button Content="" Grid.Row="1" Height="71" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="398,649,0,0" Name="Share" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="67" BorderThickness="0" Click="Share_Click" />
```

Can anyone please tell me how to use these buttons in all my pages without adding them all the time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a [**UserControl**](http://www.geekchamp.com/tips/why-and-how-to-create-a-user-control-in-windows-phone) with all the buttons in it.

```
<UserControl x:Class="WPAppTests.ButtonsUserControl" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="{StaticResource PhoneChromeBrush}">
        <!-- Buttons -->
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

When you need to use this buttons, paste this code in your page:

```
xmlns:wpAppTests="clr-namespace:WPAppTests" <!-- Your own path to the UserControl -->

<wpAppTests:ButtonsUserControl />
```

I hope this will help!